# Disable backspace and delete key with javascript in IE

Tags: javascript

Anyone know how can I disable backspace and delete key with Javascript in IE? This is my code below, but seems it's not work for IE but fine for Mozilla.

```
onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event,this)"

function isNumberKey(evt, obj)
{

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 46) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would start by reading on the OnKeyUp/onKeyDown events and what the Event object members are. This should provide you all the data you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This event handler works in all the major browsers.

```
function onkeyup(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event; // some browsers don't pass e, so get it from the window
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode; // some browsers use e.keyCode
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;  // others use e.which

    if (code == 8 || code == 46)
        return false;
}
```

You can attach the event to this function like:

```
<input onkeyup="return onkeyup()" />
```

Comment: It should be in `onkeydown` not in `onkeyup`

Answer (score 5):

**update** based on [@JoeCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187523/joecoder)s comment and the 'outdatedness' of my answer, I revised it.

```
document.querySelector([text input element]).onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || event;
    return !([8, 46].indexOf(e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode) > -1);
}
```

See also [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9r6bvaLd/)

Comment: hmm, I'm pretty sure I've used that event attachment in all the big browsers (ie, ff, safari, chrome, opera).

Comment: I tried this code in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/x9tnxqLt/2/) and I can't get it to work in IE11, Firefox 35, or Chrome 40.  It intercepts the keyup event and gets the code, but even when false is returned the browser still deletes characters from the input when backspace or delete are pressed.

Joel Potter's code doesn't work either.

Comment: Rather an old answer: the jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9r6bvaLd/ may work better

Answer (score 3):

This code cancels backspace action.

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {

    if (event.which == 8) { 

         event.preventDefault();   // turn off browser transition to the previous page 

                 // put here code you need 

        }; 

};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
        var element = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if ((element != 'input' && element != 'textarea') || $(e.target).attr("readonly")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```