# Onkeydown() does not work for delete and backspace in IE

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Does anyone know why the `onkeydown()` event does not work for <kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> key in IE? It works fine for number and character keys.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664631/disable-backspace-and-delete-key-with-javascript-in-ie

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure? .. the following sees delete and backspace fine on IE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keypress(e)
{
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) // IE
    {
        keycode = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which) // Netscape/FF/Op
    {
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    alert(keycode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="return keypress(event)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, not sure why this is not call to the function at all if pressing backspace or delete