# jQuery find if the key entered is going to increase the length of text cancel it

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery.

Objective:

- I am disabling any used input if the max length is reached for a textarea.
- I am handling keyDown event and cancelling it.

Problem:

- The user may want to delete the last word.

Here is a snippet:

```
editTweet.keydown(function(e) {
    // Can i check if the (e) is going to increase the text
    var left = Limit - editTweet.val().length;
    if (left <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    spn.text(left);
});
```

Comment: so why not using keyup event instead and 'substring' it if length is over ?

Comment: Two ways, either check to see the keystroke (del/backspace etc), or change this to keyup, and the val().length will then reflect the intended change, then you can just remove whatever was added (if not deleting)

Comment: you can capture the delete or backspace like the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664631/disable-backspace-and-delete-key-with-javascript-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using:

```
 if (e.which < 0x20) {
        // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
        // e.which === 0 - Not a character
        return;     // Do nothing
    }
```

[Copied from Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414420/how-to-prevent-user-to-enter-text-in-textarea-after-reaching-max-character-limit?rq=1)

Comment: What if you select a word and start writting? Will it erase and print the character or do nothing?